# Getting distinct elements from HTML

Tags: java, html, groovy, jsoup

I want to get distinct elements that contains some text, from a HTML page, such that the redundancy is minimal.
For example:

```html
<div class="business_card">
    <p><span id="title"><b><a href="board" target="_self">John ABC</a></b></span>
    <br>
    Director <br>
    123 456 78<br>
    <span class="email">
        <a href="mailto:john.abc@example.com">Send me an email &raquo;</a> </span></p>
</div>
```

For above HTML I would like to have these items as `Element`:

- `<a href="board" target="_self">John ABC</a>`
- `<a href="mailto:john.abc@example.com">Send me an email &raquo;</a>`
- `<p>Director<br>123 456 78</b>`

Here is the code that I have written, so far it's working quite well, except that on above example, the text `Director 123 456 78` was not collected.
I tried to add `|| element.ownText() != ""` after `!element.isBlock()` but it causes many duplications.

```java
private static def collectChildren(Element element) {
    if (element.children().size() > 0) {
        element.children().collect { it ->
            if (!element.isBlock())
                [element, collectChildren(it)]
            else collectChildren(it)
        }
    } else if (element.hasText() || element.attr("alt") != ""
            || element.attr("title") != "" || element.attr("href") != "") {
        element
    } else {
        []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:  iterate over all children and those containing interesting nodes get added to the result for the node.  those childs get removed from the current node.  if the "remaining" node `hasText` (which drops whitespace only nodes) and `isBlock` (optional), then add this element to the result too.

this works at least with the given example.  if you want to have that `<p>` node without other valid elements inside you either have to build it or you have to create it by removing the unwanted.  you might still need to do some additional filtering in the remaining node itself (e.g. also remove all remaining childs, that are `block`).  i hope this gives some imspiration:

```
@Grab('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1')
import org.jsoup.*
import org.jsoup.nodes.*

def doc = Jsoup.parse('''\
<div class="business_card">
<p>
<span id="title"><b><a href="board" target="_self">John ABC</a></b></span>
<br>
Director <br>
123 456 78<br>
<span class="email"><a href="mailto:john.abc@example.com">Send me an email &raquo;</a></span>
</p>
</div>''')

def collectChildren(Element element) {
    if (element.children().size() > 0) {
        def found = []
        element.children().findAll{
            def c = collectChildren(it).flatten()
            if (c) {
                found.addAll(c)
            } 
            return c
        }*.remove()
        if (element.hasText() && element.isBlock()) {
            found << element
        }
        found
    } else if (element.hasText() || element.attr("alt") || element.attr("title") || element.attr("href")) {
        [element]
    } else {
        []
    }
}

println collectChildren(doc.body()).flatten().join("\n")
// <a href="board" target="_self">John ABC</a>
// <a href="mailto:john.abc@example.com">Send me an email »</a>
// <p>  <br> Director <br> 123 456 78<br>  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you also use jquery to achieve your said goal?

What about doing something like:

```
 $('.buisness_card').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).text(); //Maybe set a variable here
});
```

This should loop through the `buisness_card` div and take the html values inside this div and return the text content inside each one. I made a jsfiddle to show the following below:

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qrqxf9tk/

Hopefully I'm reading you correctly and understanding you here, and jQuery could be an option.

**Edit:**

The button is only there along with the `empty()` and `append()` to setup a usable example so you can see it happen, obviously oyu can use this without either of those.